# Union type allows wrong assignment with properties from the used types

Tags: typescript

I'm having a problem understanding unions in TS, why is the below a valid assignment? I thought it would only be valid for `const a = {a:12}` or `{a:123,b:23}` or `{a:12,b:12,c:123}`.

```typescript
type abcd =
    | {
        a: number;
      }
    | {
        a: number;
        b: number;
      }
    | {
        a: number;
        b: number;
        c: number;
      };

const a: abcd = {
    a:123,
    c:234
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgRgYwCZQLwCgpagHygb022JgC4oA7AVwFs4IAnAbiOIF9XcDOTzq7GLYsTh9a9ZjygdieQsOxlK4wVKyjlAyQqwIxWocLYt0CAPYUAzsFjl4yNN14BGAEwBmADSc9HgCzoxuhAA)

It doesn't allow the assignment if I change `c` to `somethingElse`:

```typescript
const a: abcd = {
    a:123,
    somethingElse:234 // Error on this line
};
```

It gives me:

> Type '{ a: number; somethingElse: number; }' is not assignable to type 'abcd'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'somethingElse' does not exist in type 'abcd'.(2322)

Comment: It's a valid `{ a: number; }`

Comment: @VLAZ - It's not, actually, because it's an object literal, and TS doesn't allow extra properties in object literals (even though in general, supertypes can be assigned to subtypes -- this is a pragmatic "you probably didn't mean to do that" thing TS does). Try replacing `c` with `anyOtherName` and you'll get an error.

Comment: I agree , that with object-literal you can not assign a random key which the object doesn't know :( @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder excess property checks don't seem to work very well with union types as it seems to only try and find any match. Discriminated unions and intersections seem to handle excess properties better from my experience, though.

Comment: its not a valid {a:number} because it has extra c prop that {a:number} doesn't know @VLAZ

Comment: Looks like a bug or pragmatic performance limitation on excess property checks on unions. Have you had a thorough search of the bug list?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me since object literals shouldn't allow extra properties as @T.J.Crowder said. It's not a valid `{ a: number }` because it contains extra properties. It's not valid for any of the other types because it doesn't contain `b: number`

Comment: @MikeS. - Yeah, but some things that are bugs in a pure theory sense are accepted as implementation limitations by the TS team. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**

[Unions are not mutually exclusive.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38159) You can check the Work around section in this answer for a work around to achieve mutual exclusion for types with a combination of Union type, never type, and optional property.

The way that the Union type work is more closer to the `OR` gate rather than the `XOR` gate. That is, as long as the instance object satisfies one of the types in your Union type, it is considered an instance of that Union type.

Take the following for example:

```
type abcd =
  | {
    a: number;
  }
  | {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
  | {
    p: number;
    q: number;
    r: number;
  }
  | {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  };

const APY: abcd = {
  a: 123,
  p: 234,
  y: 1,
};
```

as the constant `APY` contains enough properties to be considered as an instance of `{ a: number; }` type from your union, all the other properties which can be present in the Union type are allowed.

The only limitation imposed by Union type is that those properties are not allowed which are not present in the Union type and the instance must have enough properties to satisfy one of the types present in union.

**Work around**

While the Union type itself will not help you, you can use it in conjunction with never type to achieve your desired result:

```
type abcd =
  | {
    a: number;
    b?: never;
    c?: never;
  }
  | {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c?: never;
  }
  | {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
  };

/*
  Type '{ a: number; c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'abcd'.
  Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; c: number; }' but required in type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'.
*/
const a: abcd = {
  a: 123,
  c: 234,
};
```

Comment: the workaround seems like a hack for me , but thank for your anwser :D

Comment: if only TS had some operator for XOR operation between types :(