# Is there any way to define two mutually exclusive properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

**Problem Description**

I want to define two optional properties in an interface in Typescript. One and only one of these two properties must be present in the instance object of this interface.

**What I have tried**

```
interface ISidebarCommon {
  /**
   * The label to be used in sidebar
   */
  label: string;
  /**
   * Icon class in string format for the icon of the sidebar image
   */
  icon: string;
}

interface IRoutableSidebarItem extends ISidebarCommon {
  /**
   * Role number to determine which route to redirect the user to
   * This property is mutually exclusive with children
   */
  role: number;
}

interface ITreeSidebarItem<SI> extends ISidebarCommon {
  /**
   * An array of children sidebar items.
   * This property is mutually exclusive with role
   */
  children: SI[];
}

interface ISidebar {
  [index: number]: IRoutableSidebarItem | ITreeSidebarItem<IRoutableSidebarItem
    | ITreeSidebarItem<IRoutableSidebarItem>
  >;
}
```

**Problem with current solution**

While the current solution makes sure that one of the two properties, i.e, `role` and `children`, must be present, it does not make them mutually exclusive. That is, both `role` and `children` may be present in the instance object and it will still pass the current interface check.

**Sample of Problem**

The following is an example of an instance of the `ISidebar` interface where the objects contain both `role` and `children` and the linter still doesn't show any errors:

```
const sidebarBroken: ISidebar = [
  {
    label: 'l1',
    icon: 'c1',
    role: 5,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'l2',
        icon: 'c2',
        role: 6,
        children: [
          {
            label: 'l3',
            icon: 'c3',
            role: 7,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Looks like the same problem [as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843563/union-type-allows-wrong-assignment-with-properties-from-the-used-types)

Comment: That question is more focused on the workings of Union type in Typescript while what I want to know is whether or not there is a way to force mutual exclusion of types in Typescrtipt.

I know that Union type is not the solution to assert mutual exclusion of types as Union type is closer to the logical or operation and what I want is closer to the XOR gate operation for two types.

Comment: Your answer with `never` [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist/60617060#60617060), as TypeScript can [make a discriminant property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants) out of `undefined` (`never` + optional becomes `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this by making use of the [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) type in typescript and optional properties.

What I had to do was update my interface declarations in such a that an instance of `IRoutableSidebarItem` will never have a `children` property and an instance of `ITreeSidebarItem` will never have a `role` property.

Updated example using the above mentioned workaround:

```
interface ISidebarCommon {
  /**
   * The label to be used in sidebar
   */
  label: string;
  /**
   * Icon class in string format for the icon of the sidebar image
   */
  icon: string;
}

interface IRoutableSidebarItem extends ISidebarCommon {
  /**
   * Role number to determine which route to redirect the user to
   * This property is mutually exclusive with children
   */
  role: number;
  children?: never;
}

interface ITreeSidebarItem<SI> extends ISidebarCommon {
  /**
   * An array of children sidebar items.
   * This property is mutually exclusive with role
   */
  children: SI[];
  role?: never;
}

interface ISidebar {
  [index: number]: IRoutableSidebarItem | ITreeSidebarItem<IRoutableSidebarItem
    | ITreeSidebarItem<IRoutableSidebarItem>
  >;
}

/*
  Throws a linting error
*/
const sidebarBroken: ISidebar = [
  {
    label: 'l1',
    icon: 'c1',
    role: 5,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'l2',
        icon: 'c2',
        role: 6,
        children: [
          {
            label: 'l3',
            icon: 'c3',
            role: 7,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

/*
  Doesn't throw a linting error
*/
const sidebarWorking: ISidebar = [
  {
    label: 'l1',
    icon: 'c1',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'l2',
        icon: 'c2',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'l3',
            icon: 'c3',
            role: 7,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'l1',
    icon: 'c1',
    role: 12,
  },
];
```